# Passing HTML input val to APEX controller

Tags: jquery, html, salesforce, apex

I have been researching and trying various bits of code for several days and have been unable to find a solid solution so I am coming to you all in hopes that you can point out what I am doing wrong.

On my custom VF page I am using 4 HTML input tags and when a user clicks on a generate button I want the input values to be passed into the Apex controller for manipulation.

Here is what I have now, minus code that isn't needed for this question. With it, the console output is always null...

Page Code:

```
<apex:page id="scheduler-page" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="DEMO_ScheduleOpportunityController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Generate() {
            // setting variables with data from the page
            var codRequested = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
            var velocityRequested = $("#velocity-input").val();
            var mwdcRequested = $("#mwdc-input").val();
            var seriesRequested = $("#seriesList").val();
            // these 4 values displays properly in the JS console
            console.log('codRequested: ' + codRequested);
            console.log('velocityRequested: ' + velocityRequested);
            console.log('mwdcRequested: ' + mwdcRequested);
            console.log('seriesRequested: ' + seriesRequested);
            // passing values to the actionscript
            SetInitialVariables(codRequested, velocityRequested, mwdcRequested, seriesRequested);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <apex:form id="scheduler-form">

        <apex:actionFunction name="SetInitialVariables" action="{!GenerateSchedule}">
            <apex:param name="codRequested" value="" />
            <apex:param name="velocityRequested" value="" />
            <apex:param name="mwdcRequested" value="" />
            <apex:param name="seriesRequested" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>

        <c:DEMOscheduleGeneration opportunity="{!opportunity}" seriesMap="{!seriesMap}" />
    </apex:form>

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" />
</body>
```

Component Code:

```
<apex:component>
  <div id="generateContainer" class="container">
    <!-- generate button -->
    <div id="generate-button-wrap">
        <a id="generate" onclick="Generate()">Generate</a>
        <!-- calls JQ Generate function -->
    </div>
  </div>
</apex:component>
```

Controller Code:

```
public PageReference GenerateSchedule() {        
    String series = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('seriesRequested');
    String mwdc = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('mwdcRequested');
    String velocity = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('velocityRequested');
    String cod = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('codRequested');
    System.debug('Series: ' + series);
    System.debug('MWdc: ' + mwdc);
    System.debug('Velocity: ' + velocity);
    System.debug('COD: ' + cod);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Controller code is absolutely incorrect. In the controller code you included some js (the same as in `function Generate() {` but VF controllers should be written with Apex. So, this code can't be compiled at all. Please include correct controller code.

Comment: Thanks that was a complete oversight when I made this post due to my mind being fried. I copied the wrong code into this post but in my controller it was set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your fix is pretty simple: You are using `jQuery` and the `$` is conflicting with internal Salesforce functions. You need to use noConflict. Do this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
// setting variables with data from the page
var codRequested = j$("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
var velocityRequested = j$("#velocity-input").val();
....
```

Wherever your would use `$` use `j$`. This should fix your issue.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick, everything in my controller is still debugging as null's.

Comment: Now you need to inspect the code. Right clicking on the page allows you to set breakpoints on this javascript code to see if the values are correct. Possible other things that could be wrong - if you are using native inputs, then salesforce appends to the id that you have provided - use a unique class name instead. Also check that jQuery is being included properly. You know, you hardly need jQuery here - all you are doing is referencing some id values.